# Why path does not exist when built programmaticaly

Tags: python-3.x, path

Can someone explain this please, it's driving me crazy:

```
text = '!!!advanced_search.png'
path = './images/' + text.split('!!!')[1]
print(path)  # -> ./images/advanced_search.png
print(os.path.exists(path)) # -> False
print(os.path.exists('./images/advanced_search.png')) # -> True
```

Comment: Does `path == './images/advanced_search.png'`? Have you looked at `repr(path)`?

Comment: does it work when you append `+ ""` to path on line four ?

Comment: ```path == './images/advanced_search.png'``` returns False. But why ???
@Marged, what do you mean ? Something like ```print(os.path.exists(path + ""))```

Comment: Ok, very good call: ```repr(path) -> './images/advanced_search.png\n'``` Because actually, in my code, text comes from somewhere else. Thank you @jonrsharpe